# the source attachment does not contain the source for the file Throwables.class

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to run the following code in Eclipse but get this exception:

> Source Attachment does not contain the source for the file Throwables.class.

I tried to change the path of the required jar, but is not working.

```
    package automationFramework;

    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

    import org.openqa.selenium.*;

    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class FirstTestCase {
private static WebDriver driver = null;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // Create a new instance of the Firefox driver

    driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    //Put a Implicit wait, this means that any search for elements on the page could take the time the implicit wait is set for before throwing exception

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    //Launch the Online Store Website

    driver.get("http://www.store.demoqa.com");

    // Find the element that's ID attribute is 'account'(My Account)

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='account']/a")).click();

    // Find the element that's ID attribute is 'log' (Username)

    // Enter Username on the element found by above desc.

    driver.findElement(By.id("log")).sendKeys("testuser_1");

    // Find the element that's ID attribute is 'pwd' (Password)

    // Enter Password on the element found by the above desc.

    driver.findElement(By.id("pwd")).sendKeys("Test@123");

    // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element

    driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();

    // Print a Log In message to the screen

    System.out.println(" Login Successfully, now it is the time to Log Off buddy.");

    // Find the element that's ID attribute is 'account_logout' (Log Out)

    driver.findElement (By.xpath(".//*[@id='account_logout']/a")).click();

    // Close the driver

    driver.quit();

        }

}
```

Comment: It's not the exception. Just click "OK" in that dialog you are getting, and look for the real exception in the console view.

Comment: Is the program running properly?

Comment: I get the same thing.  There is no, "OK" button.  And it's already configured to look for the src.zip file.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like you haven't showed Eclipse the source code for the Java library. There should be a button to search for it, and in the JDK files, there should be a `src.zip` file.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That helped me.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the it is not able to find a throwable exception to throw in your included library. You need to import the throwable java class